# Rails Cached partial in layout is rendered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, layout

I am trying to cache a partial which is rendered in a layout. This partial is computationally expensive so I only want to compute it once. It is not controller specific so the usual fragment caching doesn't seem to apply. I decided to use Rails.cache.fetch('menu') for the caching instead. Here is what the contents of the partial look like.

```
<% Rails.cache.fetch('menu') do %>
  Partial code...
<% end %>
```

But when I do this it renders the partial twice. For some reason it stopped doing this in my development environment so I decided to try and deploy it. I am not so lucky with my production environment. The partial itself generates a menu that includes links to a lot of the records in the site to help improve navigation.

I originally tried putting the cache statement in the layout file but then it was rendering the layout twice.

I recently added a jQuery hack to remove the duplicate html so that it kinda "works" for now, but I would rather get it working properly. I don't want to go to the trouble of installing some complicated caching system such as Redis, that requires me to run another server program. That would be overkill for the task. There must be something in rails that is well suited to caching parts of layouts.

Should I try something completely different or is this a bug in rails? If it is a bug then is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: Maybe you should try caching only the computationally expensive query (I'm assuming its a dbquery?)? Heroku article I find useful on rails caching http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies

Comment: I could try and cache the queries. The way that I build the menu involves a lot of separate queries. Right now this is all built into a sub partial that is called by the main partial. The sub partial calls itself recursively.

Comment: It would require a lot of changes to move all the queries to the application controller. I wonder if render_to_string can be cached properly in the application controller? Then I could just render to a string and pass the string on to the layout. I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of caching the partial in the view, I created a helper method that returns the rendered partial.

```
#Returns a menu for the application layout
def menu
  Rails.cache.fetch('menu') { render :partial => 'all/menu' }
end
```

Then all I needed in the layout is this line
    <% menu %>

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your production cache.  Chances are you had a logic error that was causing it to render twice.  In development, the cache is usually disabled so that's why when you fixed the problem it went away in development.  If you have redeployed, the issue is probably gone from the production code as well, but if the cache has not been cleared, it will keep displaying the cached logic error.

Comment: I have the cache enabled in development. Still don't know why it went away in development. In production if I restart the server then the partial is recomputed the next time someone visits the site. This didn't make the problem go away.

Comment: The partial is not recomputed by restarting the server.  The partial is only recomputed by clearing the cache.  Restarting rails does not clear the cache.